# play framework internet explorer logging

Tags: internet-explorer, playframework, console

I'm using Play Framework to write a small web application.I'm testing my application with Internet Explorer.
My application get some data from an MSSQL database.

My problem is, that when I'm testing my application with Google Chrome, then I see my SQL queries in the console, but if I change to Internet Explorer, I can't see my SQL queries anymore.

Can someone help me, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In which console ? Shell ?

Comment: sorry for my bad explain, I'm a bit new in this thema, I though about the command line console, when i start my play projekt with "activator run" in the cmd, then I can see in this cmd my SQL queries (after I have executed an SQL query , and when I test my app with google chrome)

Comment: Well let's take it apart, for some reason you are probably using an old version of IE which can't display your site, the request never gets completed and therefore play is not executing a request nor does your action to list all 'items' gets fired. Is there some ajax involved ?